# Temperature Converter: °C to K

Tags: python-3.x, object-oriented, classes

### What it does

- Converts melting point and boiling point from degrees celsius to kelvin
- These are in a dict which is in a tuple as no changes should be made to it
- No user input

### Purpose

Learning exercise to understand classes and OOP

### What I need help with

- Is this how you do classes?
- Is this correct OOP?
- Suggest any improvements?

#### Code:

```py
from typing import Dict


class ConvertToKelvin:
    def __init__(self, substance: str, data: Dict[str, int]):
        self.substance = substance
        self.data = data

    def to_kelvin(self, celsius: int) -> int:
        return celsius + 273

    def __str__(self):
        sub = self.substance
        mp = self.to_kelvin(self.data["mp"])
        bp = self.to_kelvin(self.data["bp"])
        return f'{sub}:\n mp: {mp}K\n bp: {bp}K\n'


data = (
    ConvertToKelvin(
        'water',
        {
            'bp': 0,
            'mp': 100
        }
    ),
    ConvertToKelvin(
        'imaginary',
        {
           'bp': 30,
           'mp': 120
        }
    ),
)

print('\n'.join(str(i) for i in data))
```

#### Output:

```
water:
 mp: 373K
 bp: 273K

imaginary:
 mp: 393K
 bp: 303K
```

Comment: `to_kelvin(self, celsius: int)` seems more like a general utility function rather than a method related to or acting on `ConvertToKelvin`.  If this was more integrated, I might expect `ConvertToKelvin` to have a property `celsius` similar to `substance` and that one would get the converted value via `to_kelvin(self)`.

Comment: That’s right, it’s because I’m so used to just using functions to do things having a hard time grasping OOP as for some things I just don’t get how they can be used as a ‘blueprint’

Comment: Is `bp` = "boiling point" and `mp` = "melting point"?  Do you have those switched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- ConvertToKelvin sounds like a method (it's a verb), when you actually need a noun
- You're actually capturing two different things - a temperature, and a substance
- The figure of 273 is incorrect and should actually be 273.15
- Avoid dictionaries for the purposes of internal state representation
- These are simple enough that a `dataclass` is well-suited, and should be immutable given the nature of your data hence why `frozen` is set
- Your use of `int` should probably be `float` instead. Temperatures are not discrete values.

### Suggested

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Temperature:
    celsius: float

    @property
    def kelvin(self) -> float:
        return self.celsius + 273.15

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.kelvin} K'


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Substance:
    name: str
    melt: Temperature
    boil: Temperature

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f'{self.name}:\n'
            f' melt: {self.melt}\n'
            f' boil: {self.boil}\n'
        )


substances = (
    Substance(
        'water',
        Temperature(celsius=0),
        Temperature(celsius=100),
    ),
    Substance(
        '2-methylobenzenol (o-cresol)',
        Temperature(celsius=30),
        Temperature(celsius=191),
    ),
)

print('\n'.join(str(i) for i in substances))
```

Comment: Thank you, I used your last answer as a base to get familiar with classes and also to understand what you done which was impressive as all the guides deal only with user input like setting a value manually. There’s just one thing I don’t get how would you implement this as a ‘blueprint’? Thanks for correcting me on the precise value of converting to K, since you seem to be a man who loves precision, I think it’s just `K` Rather than degrees K :) but it was a good point for using a float thanks again

Comment: You're right; I never knew that! Per Wikipedia, _Unlike the degree Fahrenheit and degree Celsius, the kelvin is not referred to or written as a degree._

Comment: As for a "blueprint", there's a large collection of strategies for class representation in Python and which to use varies widely based on circumstance.

Comment: I’m just curious how you know some of the stuff you come out with, can’t find any guides that show the cool things you’ve shown me

Comment: Time in the job, research in the PEPs and the Python documentation (most of the Python tutorial content on the internet is junk)

Comment: I was going to use this structure replacing the `Substance` class with `Thing` class and `Temperature` to `Calculate` for printing the price and names of things I want to buy plus the total, is it possible to add up the temperatures in this example or would I be better of changing to a dict for this case? @Reinderien

Comment: Stop using dicts. Don't name a class Calculate - that's the name of a method (verb), not a class (noun)

Comment: Point taken, but is it possible to add up the temps for a total using this structure? That’s all I want to know @Reinderien

Comment: Let's please continue this in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126623/temperature-classes

Answer (score 2):

Very nice question and great use of types! Let us step through your questions one at a time

---

**`Is this how you do classes`**

I would argue *no*, but let us take a step back and look at how brilliant classifies as a `class:`

> In object-oriented programming, a class is a blueprint for creating
> objects (a particular data structure), providing initial values for
> state (member variables or attributes), and implementations of
> behavior (member functions or methods).
>
> The user-defined objects are created using the class keyword. The
> class is a blueprint that defines a nature of a future object. An
> instance is a specific object created from a particular class. Classes
> are used to create and manage new objects and support inheritance—a
> key ingredient in object-oriented programming and a mechanism of
> reusing code.
> [image]

So my problem with your class is that it is *really* not describing an object is it? It is really describing a *function* (please convert my temperature from X to Y).

---

**`Is this correct OOP?`**

As mentioned above I would not use classes in the way you are using them from a design standpoint. However, your implementation seems good. You are using types and overall it looks good.

---

**`Suggest any improvements?`**

Ok. So if `ConvertToKelvin` does not describe an object, what would? Something that comes to my mind is `Kelvin`, `Celsius` or even `Temperature`

Something like ought to do the trick

```
class Celsius:
    absolute_zero = -273.15

    def __init__(self, temperature=0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    def to_kelvin(self):
        return self.temperature - self.absolute_zero

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        return self._temperature_C

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        if value < self.absolute_zero:
            raise ValueError(f"Temperature below {self.absolute_zero} is not possible")
        self._temperature_C = value
        self._temperature_F = self.to_fahrenheit()
        self._temperature_K = self.to_kelvin()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"""Temperature:
  Celcius: {self._temperature_C}
  Fahrenheit: {self._temperature_F}
  Kelvin: {self._temperature_K} 
"""
```

The `@property` lets us even raise an error if the temperature is not valid. As can be seen by running something like

```
    outside = Celsius(50)
    print(outside)
    outside.temperature = 25
    print(outside)
    # outside.temperature = -300
    # print(outside)
```

Comment: You’re right because all I really know are functions, I just thought how the hell can this be a blueprint for something but I seen some people using classes where I would just use functions, thanks a lot for the tips :) I’m starting to get it more now